# Using one list index as reference in a for loop

Tags: python

I am looking to add text from one list (ListC) to another list (ListB) based on boolean values of a third list (ListA). So all elements of ListB gets an addition but it changes based on the index of ListA. The change should occur only when the index in ListA is True.

```
ListA = [True, False, True, False, False, False, True]

ListB = ['T1', 'T2', 'T3', 'T4', 'T5', 'T6', 'T7']

ListC = ['s1', 's2', 's3']
```

The expected end result would be a listD (see that first and second elements of List D has s1 and s2 only enters on the third element as in ListA is True, False, True):

```
ListD = ['s1 + T1', 's1 + T2', 's2 + T3', 's2 + T4', 's2 + T5', 's2 + T6', 's3 + T7']
```

the idea is to replace the existing code of:

```
for i in range(0,2):
    ListD[i] = 's1' +  ListB[i]

for l in range (2,5):
    ListD[l] = 's2' + ListB[l]

for w in range(5,7):
    ListD[w] = 's3'+ ListB[w]
```

Any suggestions on how to do this?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: are you sure about the output, why does s1+T2 exist even the list A has false value at second index?

Comment: if i understood correctly, any True in listA means that we change the added value (on ListB) one position to the right on listC?

Comment: Looks like inconsistency in input and output results. Probably last True should be in ListA not in the last position but in last but one.

Comment: I don't understand the logic to get `listD`. Also you never used `listA` in your code, so what is it for?

Comment: ListA is the trigger to change which ListC to use. Whenever ListA index is True, a new ListC element is used. In other words, ListA as False does not change which element of ListC to use.

Comment: So the first value will always be `True`?

Comment: Not necessarily, it may be False

Comment: @RafaelCasteloBranco If first element is False then which element of ListC to use first? Looks like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64226283/941531) is the correct variant. Or almost correct. Swapping in that answer lines `c += ...` and `...append...` may be another correct variant, depending what you exactly need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
cdx = -1
ListD=[]
for bdx, b in enumerate(ListB):
    cdx+=int(ListA[bdx])
    ListD.append(ListC[max(0, cdx)]+' + '+b)
    
ListD
```

Which outputs:

```
['s1 + T1', 's1 + T2', 's2 + T3', 's2 + T4', 's2 + T5', 's2 + T6', 's3 + T7']
```

Although I am not really sure about how you are treating the first `True` in your list and what would be the output if there is a `False` at index 0. Assuming you want the first item in the list anyways, this code will work. If you want to do something different with the first `False`, it might require some changes

Answer (score 1):

```
In[115]: c = 0
In[116]: for i, flag in enumerate(ListA):
    ...:     ListD.append(ListC[c] + ' + ' + ListB[i])
    ...:     c += int(flag)
    ...:     
In[117]: ListD
Out[117]: ['s1 + T1', 's2 + T2', 's2 + T3', 's3 + T4', 's3 + T5', 's3 + T6', 's3 + T7']
```

But I don't see that your example takes the first `True` in mind and that's why my result is different

Comment: Probably you should start from `c = -1` and do `c += ...` before appending. At least then output will be closer to questioner's output.

Comment: Yes, that will do the exact result. But it seems strange in the example that only the second `True` value changes behaviour so that's why I made that version where every `True` value makes the difference

Comment: I expect that in the input example the last True should be in last but one position of ListA. Anyway to figure out the correct algorithm example input/output should be corrected by questioner.

Comment: Hi @busfighter not exactly what I was looking as the second element of ListA is False, so the second element of ListD should have st + T1. The change must occur when the index in ListA is True and not when it is false

Comment: ListA values can change ListC member before or after appending to ListD. What is your case?

Comment: I think I found an answer but haven't tested on all possible scenario:

c = 0
for i, flag in enumerate(ListA):     
        ListD.append(ListC[c] + ' + ' + ListB[i])
        if ListA[i+1] == True:
            c += 1

Comment: you can change my answer as described in the first comment by @Arty and it will do the same result as in your example

Comment: Probably just to swap lines `c += ...` and `...append...` is needed to make it correct.

Answer (score 0):

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

ListA = [True, False, True, False, False, False, True]
ListB = ['T1', 'T2', 'T3', 'T4', 'T5', 'T6', 'T7']
ListC = ['s1', 's2', 's3']
ListD = []

count = 0
for i in range(len(ListA)):
    if ListA[i]:
        ListD.append("{} + {}".format(ListC[count], ListB[i]))
    else:
        ListD.append("{} + {}".format(ListC[count], ListB[i]))
        if count < 2:
            count += 1
```